# Is there a faster way to convert an arbitrary large integer to a big endian sequence of bytes?

Tags: python, optimization

I have this Python code to do this:

```
from struct import pack as _pack

def packl(lnum, pad = 1):
    if lnum < 0:
        raise RangeError("Cannot use packl to convert a negative integer "
                         "to a string.")
    count = 0
    l = []
    while lnum > 0:
        l.append(lnum & 0xffffffffffffffffL)
        count += 1
        lnum >>= 64
    if count <= 0:
        return '\0' * pad
    elif pad >= 8:
        lens = 8 * count % pad
        pad = ((lens != 0) and (pad - lens)) or 0
        l.append('>' + 'x' * pad + 'Q' * count)
        l.reverse()
        return _pack(*l)
    else:
        l.append('>' + 'Q' * count)
        l.reverse()
        s = _pack(*l).lstrip('\0')
        lens = len(s)
        if (lens % pad) != 0:
            return '\0' * (pad - lens % pad) + s
        else:
            return s
```

This takes approximately 174 usec to convert `2**9700 - 1` to a string of bytes on my machine.  If I'm willing to use the Python 2.7 and Python 3.x specific `bit_length` method, I can shorten that to 159 usecs by pre-allocating the `l` array to be the exact right size at the very beginning and using `l[something] =` syntax instead of `l.append`.

Is there anything I can do that will make this faster?  This will be used to convert large prime numbers used in cryptography as well as some (but not many) smaller numbers.

**Edit**

This is currently the fastest option in Python < 3.2, it takes about half the time either direction as the accepted answer:

```
def packl(lnum, padmultiple=1):
    """Packs the lnum (which must be convertable to a long) into a
       byte string 0 padded to a multiple of padmultiple bytes in size. 0
       means no padding whatsoever, so that packing 0 result in an empty
       string.  The resulting byte string is the big-endian two's
       complement representation of the passed in long."""

    if lnum == 0:
        return b'\0' * padmultiple
    elif lnum < 0:
        raise ValueError("Can only convert non-negative numbers.")
    s = hex(lnum)[2:]
    s = s.rstrip('L')
    if len(s) & 1:
        s = '0' + s
    s = binascii.unhexlify(s)
    if (padmultiple != 1) and (padmultiple != 0):
        filled_so_far = len(s) % padmultiple
        if filled_so_far != 0:
            s = b'\0' * (padmultiple - filled_so_far) + s
    return s

def unpackl(bytestr):
    """Treats a byte string as a sequence of base 256 digits
    representing an unsigned integer in big-endian format and converts
    that representation into a Python integer."""

    return int(binascii.hexlify(bytestr), 16) if len(bytestr) > 0 else 0
```

In Python 3.2 the `int` class has `to_bytes` and `from_bytes` functions that can accomplish this **much** more quickly that the method given above.

Comment: What does `pad` do? A docstring would be handy to understand the usage.

Comment: @Scott As far as I can tell, the output is zero-padded at the front to the next multiple-of-pad number of bytes.

Comment: Reagrdelss of eing a localy used variable, you shoul avoid using a variable name sucha s "l" - it looks too much like "1" on most fonts to keep readability.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - That's precisely right.  I wanted to use this in situations where I wanted to dump it into a slot that was exactly 64 bits long, or 128 bits long or something like that.

Comment: @Scott Griffiths - You're right, it does need a docstring.  *embarrassed look*

Comment: I think you can do without the `encode('ascii')` in your `packl` function (as long as you also replace `b'L'` with `'L'` and `b'0'` with `'0'` if using Python 3). Makes it another 10% faster for me :)

Comment: @Scott Giffiths: You're right. I wrongly assumed that `unhexlify` would demand a bytestring as input. Also, the `rstrip` can be completely removed in Python 3. So if I wanted to be extra-concerned with that sort of thing, I could make a separate Python 3 version that omitted it.

Comment: Thought you might like to know I've borrowed your new method as an optimisation in the [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/source/detail?r=875) module. Cheers!

Comment: @Scott Griffiths - Well, it's only partly mine. A new answer by @bk0 was the inspiration. But that's nice to know. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness and for future readers of this question:

Starting in Python 3.2, there are functions [`int.from_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) and [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) that perform the conversion between `bytes` and `int` objects in a choice of byte orders.

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering though if the endian flags will slow it down or not. We'll see.

Comment: Even with the endian flag, it still takes 1/3rd the time (or less) of the fastest method I'd found so far.

Comment: `int.to_bytes()` requires a `length` parameter: `n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big') or b'\0'` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes/12859903#12859903))

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution calling the Python/C API via `ctypes`.  Currently, it uses NumPy, but if NumPy is not an option, it could be done purely with `ctypes`.

```
import numpy
import ctypes
PyLong_AsByteArray = ctypes.pythonapi._PyLong_AsByteArray
PyLong_AsByteArray.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object,
                               numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer(numpy.uint8),
                               ctypes.c_size_t,
                               ctypes.c_int,
                               ctypes.c_int]

def packl_ctypes_numpy(lnum):
    a = numpy.zeros(lnum.bit_length()//8 + 1, dtype=numpy.uint8)
    PyLong_AsByteArray(lnum, a, a.size, 0, 1)
    return a
```

On my machine, this is 15 times faster than your  approach.

**Edit:** Here is the same code using `ctypes` only and returning a string instead of a NumPy array:

```
import ctypes
PyLong_AsByteArray = ctypes.pythonapi._PyLong_AsByteArray
PyLong_AsByteArray.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object,
                               ctypes.c_char_p,
                               ctypes.c_size_t,
                               ctypes.c_int,
                               ctypes.c_int]

def packl_ctypes(lnum):
    a = ctypes.create_string_buffer(lnum.bit_length()//8 + 1)
    PyLong_AsByteArray(lnum, a, len(a), 0, 1)
    return a.raw
```

This is another two times faster, totalling to a speed-up factor of 30 on my machine.

Comment: Won't that use the system native endianness though?

Comment: @Karl: No, it won't.  The fourth parameter to `PyLong_AsByteArray()` indicates which endianness to use: `0` means big endian, anything else means little endian.

Comment: Awesome. Now I wish this were exposed directly... :/

Comment: Has this API changed much over different versions of Python?

Comment: And, of course, you cheated just a little.  :-)  You do not support padding.  But that's a very small detail.

Comment: @Omnifarious: The function `_PyLong_AsByteArray()` did not change at least since Python 2.4, and I don't think `ctypes` is available for earlier versions of Python (it ships with Python since 2.5).  I tested it successfully with Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and 3.2, so it seems rather robust, though I'm not even sure if it is part of the official interface.

Comment: @Sven Marnach - But Python 2.6 seems to be missing the `bit_length` function.  Did you cobble together your own?

Comment: @Omnifarious: Regarding the padding: It's trivial to include this -- `_PyLong_AsByteArray()` uses the whole buffer up to the given size.  If the buffer is too small, it indicates an error by returning `-1` (`0` meaning success).

Comment: @Omnifarious: No, for 2.6 I used `i = 2**9700-1` and hard-coded size `1213` for testing purposes :)  Do you need it for 2.6 as well?

Comment: @Sven Marnach - Not really.  I'm writing something that won't be really seen in the wild for a few months, so I'm comfortable ditching 2.6 and earlier.

Comment: @Omnifarious: ok -- otherwise it would be possible to access the internal fields of a `long` to extract the bit length.  A final remark:  The code above will choke on regular `int` objects, it only works with `long`s.  For Python 3.x, this distinction doesn't exist any more.

Comment: @Sven Marnach - In fact, it crashes Python if it's not a `long`.  :-)  And I fixed it so that's not a problem.  This code is going into a GPLv3+ work.  I assume you don't care.  Do you wish attribution?  I think if I want 2.6 compatibility I will just fall back to my original method.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Glad to hear it will be free software.  No attribution, of course.

Comment: `int(binascii.hexlify(stringbytes), 16)` is faster than `ctypes.pythonapi._PyLong_FromByteArray`. Whoulda thunk it?

Comment: @Omnifarious: I'm surprised indeed, especially after having a glance at the source code of the latter -- looks like a pretty straight-forward C implementation.

Comment: @Sven Marnach - Feel free to test it out with `timeit`. I was quite surprised too. My guess is that it's `ctypes` overhead.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I take your word for it, and `ctypes` overhead seems a good explanation.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you really should just be using numpy, which I'm sure has something or other built in for this. It might also be faster to hack around with the `array` module. But I'll take a stab at it anyway.

IMX, creating a generator and using a list comprehension and/or built-in summation is faster than a loop that appends to a list, because the appending can be done internally. Oh, and 'lstrip' on a large string has got to be costly.

Also, some style points: special cases aren't special enough; and you appear not to have gotten the memo about the new `x if y else z` construct. :) Although we don't need it anyway. ;)

```
from struct import pack as _pack


Q_size = 64
Q_bitmask = (1L << Q_size) - 1L


def quads_gen(a_long):
    while a_long:
        yield a_long & Q_bitmask
        a_long >>= Q_size


def pack_long_big_endian(a_long, pad = 1):
    if lnum < 0:
        raise RangeError("Cannot use packl to convert a negative integer "
                         "to a string.")
    qs = list(reversed(quads_gen(a_long)))
    # Pack the first one separately so we can lstrip nicely.
    first = _pack('>Q', qs[0]).lstrip('\x00')
    rest = _pack('>%sQ' % len(qs) - 1, *qs[1:])
    count = len(first) + len(rest)
    # A little math trick that depends on Python's behaviour of modulus
    # for negative numbers - but it's well-defined and documented
    return '\x00' * (-count % pad) + first + rest
```

Comment: I shouldn't have voted you up.  Your code has numerous errors.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to post a follow-up to Sven's answer (which works great). The *opposite* operation - going from arbitrarily long bytes object to Python Integer object requires the following (because there is no PyLong_FromByteArray() C API function that I can find):

```
import binascii

def unpack_bytes(stringbytes):
    #binascii.hexlify will be obsolete in python3 soon
    #They will add a .tohex() method to bytes class
    #Issue 3532 bugs.python.org
    return int(binascii.hexlify(stringbytes), 16)
```

Comment: There is in fact a `_PyLong_FromByteArray` function (at least in Python 2.7 and Python 3). I'm using it. But your method would probably be pretty fast too.

Comment: This is, in fact, faster than calling _PyLong_FromByteArray using ctypes. How bizarre. Even better, I don't have to check if the input is a `memoryview` because hexlify handles those, and I don't have to convert to an `int` in Python 2.7 in order to make the value into a straight `int` if it's small enough to not need to be a `long`.

Comment: Also, using `hex(lnum)' and `binascii.unhexlify` (with a little extra glue) is also faster than the ctypes option.

Comment: Weird. I looked through the Python 3.1.x C API reference and couldn't find PyLong_FromByteArray().