# writing a 1024 bits length decimal number in a binary file with python

Tags: python, cryptography

i have actually obtained a 1024 bits length decimal number (representing half of a rsa key of 2048 bits).

I would like to then write this number into a binary file, e.g. the bytes of this file will directly represent the number.

I figured for example how to do so with a long number, "4444" for example:

```
with open('test','wb') as f:
     for b in struct.pack('>L',4444):
         f.write(b)
```

i then get those bytes in the binary file : 00 00 11 5c

however, how can i do so for long numbers, like a 1024 bit length one?

thanks for any answer!

Comment: In what format do you hold the decimal number? Is it an `str` of decimal digits?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358285/is-there-a-faster-way-to-convert-an-arbitrary-large-integer-to-a-big-endian-seque/4358429#4358429 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670350/how-do-i-write-a-long-integer-as-binary-in-python

Comment: ah thanks rob for those! i passed on the second one as i just saw 'long integer' and thought it was long in the sense of C type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> binascii.unhexlify('{:0{}x}'.format(19, int(1024/4)))
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can treat any positive Python integer as a base-256 encoded `bytestring` and encode and decode one like this:

```
import math

def hexrepr(b):  # bytearray arg
    return ' '.join(("%02x" % i) for i in b)

def hexstr(b):  # bytearray arg
    return "'%s'" % ''.join('\\x'+("%02x" % i) for i in b)

def roundup(n, m):  # round n up to nearest whole m
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        add = m // abs(m)
        return ((n+m-add) // m) * m

def base256_encode(n, minlen=0): # int/long to byte array
    if n > 0:
        arr = []
        while n:
            n, rem = divmod(n, 256)
            arr.append(rem)
        b = bytearray(reversed(arr))
    elif n == 0:
        b = bytearray(b'\x00')
    else:
        raise ValueError

    if minlen > 0 and len(b) < minlen: # zero padding needed?
        b = (minlen-len(b)) * '\x00' + b
    return b

def base256_decode(a_bytearray): # bytearray to number
    return reduce(lambda a,i: a*256 + i, a_bytearray, 0)

n = 4444  # must be unsigned integer
nbits = int(math.floor(math.log(n, 2)) + 1)  # number of bits needed to represent n
print 'n:', format(n, ',d')
print('nbits: {}'.format(nbits))
print('roundup(nbits, 8): {}'.format(roundup(nbits, 8)))

encoded = base256_encode(n, roundup(nbits, 8)/8)
print 'encoded = base256_encode(n, roundup(nbits, 8)/8)'
print 'hexstr(encoded):', hexstr(encoded)
print 'encoded:', hexrepr(encoded)
print 'decoded:', format(base256_decode(encoded), ',d')
```

Which produces the following for `n = 4444`:

Output:

```
n: 4,444
nbits: 13
roundup(nbits, 8): 16
encoded = base256_encode(n, roundup(nbits, 8)/8)
hexstr(encoded): '\x11\x5c'
encoded: 11 5c
decoded: 4,444
```

Comment: Well, the two answers work in my case, and thank you very much both of you! I choose the answer of Ignacio (however, you did a pretty impressive answer martineau)for simplicity.