# Convert unsigned long int of arbitrary size to byte string

Tags: string, python-2.7, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I am looking from something to convert a large unsigned int into a byte array so that I will be able to send it over a serial port.

In python 3.2 there is built in function [to_bytes](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html) to convert long integers to return a byte array. However this is not available in python 2.7. Likewise python 2.7 has a struct lib, but that library does not handle arbitrarily large ints.  There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670350/how-do-i-write-a-long-integer-as-binary-in-python) on stack overflow, however the accepted answer is using pickle. That would not help me as I am looking to send the long int without loosing compression. I can of course iterate over the int and come up with something custom, but I was hoping there is something available to handle the heavy lifting for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `x` format specifier to convert it to a hex string, add a leading `0` if the length is odd, and then decode it as `'hex'` to turn it into bytes. Not the fastest way, but simple.

```
>>> '{:x}'.format(20L).decode('hex')
'\x14'
```