# Slow Big Int Output in python

Tags: python, biginteger

Is there anyway to improve performance of "str(bigint)" and "print bigint" in python ? Printing big integer values takes a lot of time. I tried to use the following recursive technique :

```
def p(x,n):
    if n < 10:
            sys.stdout.write(str(x))
            return
    n >>= 1
    l = 10**n
    k = x/l
    p(k,n)
    p(x-k*l,n)
```

n = number of digits, 
x = bigint

But the method fails for certain cases where x in a sub call has leading zeros. Is there any alternative to it or any faster method. ( Please do not suggest using any external module or library ).

Comment: Are you saying the built-in `print` is slow?

Comment: What's wrong with `print(x)`?

Comment: `print`ing is slow, and I don't think you can improve on the speed of `str(bigint)` since it is done in C. Why would you need to print fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion from a Python integer to a string has a running of O(n^2) where n is the length of the number. For sufficiently large numbers, it will be slow. For a 1,000,001 digit number, str() takes approximately 24 seconds on my computer.

If you are really needing to convert very large numbers to a string, your recursive algorithm is a good approach.

The following version of your recursive code should work:

```
def p(x,n=0):
    if n == 0:
        n = int(x.bit_length() * 0.3)
    if n < 100:
        return str(x)
    n >>= 1
    l = 10**n
    a,b = divmod(x, l)
    upper = p(a,n)
    lower = p(b,n).rjust(n, "0")
    return upper + lower
```

It automatically estimates the number of digits in the output. It is about 4x faster for a 1,000,001 digit number.

If you need to go faster, you'll probably need to use an external library.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. Though the approach is still not fast enough( may be i can try an iterative one ) but it works.

Comment: @kiesel-x Not using an external library is a challenge. Several years ago I wrote a pure Python library that uses an arbitrary radix for the internal representation. Output is O(n) and for large enough values, arithmetic operations are faster than standard Python. If you're interested, I can get it cleaned up and posted.

Comment: sorry for replying so late. I am interested in your fast python library. Can you please post it or provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

For interactive applications, the built-in `print` and `str` functions run in the blink of an eye.

```
>>> print(2435**356)
392312129667763499898262143039114894750417507355276682533585134425186395679473824899297157270033375504856169200419790241076407862555973647354250524748912846623242257527142883035360865888685267386832304026227703002862158054991819517588882346178140891206845776401970463656725623839442836540489638768126315244542314683938913576544051925370624663114138982037489687849052948878188837292688265616405774377520006375994949701519494522395226583576242344239113115827276205685762765108568669292303049637000429363186413856005994770187918867698591851295816517558832718248949393330804685089066399603091911285844172167548214009780037628890526044957760742395926235582458565322761344968885262239207421474370777496310304525709023682281880997037864251638836009263968398622163509788100571164918283951366862838187930843528788482813390723672536414889756154950781741921331767254375186751657589782510334001427152820459605953449036021467737998917512341953008677012880972708316862112445813219301272179609511447382276509319506771439679815804130595523836440825373857906867090741932138749478241373687043584739886123984717258259445661838205364797315487681003613101753488707273055848670365977127506840194115511621930636465549468994140625
>>> str(2435**356)
'392312129667763499898262143039114894750417507355276682533585134425186395679473824899297157270033375504856169200419790241076407862555973647354250524748912846623242257527142883035360865888685267386832304026227703002862158054991819517588882346178140891206845776401970463656725623839442836540489638768126315244542314683938913576544051925370624663114138982037489687849052948878188837292688265616405774377520006375994949701519494522395226583576242344239113115827276205685762765108568669292303049637000429363186413856005994770187918867698591851295816517558832718248949393330804685089066399603091911285844172167548214009780037628890526044957760742395926235582458565322761344968885262239207421474370777496310304525709023682281880997037864251638836009263968398622163509788100571164918283951366862838187930843528788482813390723672536414889756154950781741921331767254375186751657589782510334001427152820459605953449036021467737998917512341953008677012880972708316862112445813219301272179609511447382276509319506771439679815804130595523836440825373857906867090741932138749478241373687043584739886123984717258259445661838205364797315487681003613101753488707273055848670365977127506840194115511621930636465549468994140625'
```

If however you are printing big integers to (standard output, say) so that they can be read (from standard input) by another process, and you are finding the binary-to-decimal operations impacting the overall performance, you can look at [Is there a faster way to convert an arbitrary large integer to a big endian sequence of bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358285/is-there-a-faster-way-to-convert-an-arbitrary-large-integer-to-a-big-endian-seque) (although the accepted answer suggests numpy, which is an external library, though there are other suggestions).

Comment: `print` isn't really that fast, (maybe a couple hundred lines per second for me) but that doesn't have anything to do with the string conversion.

Comment: Okay the comment on `print` is withdrawn, but I would say "fast enough, right?" Because for the slowness to really impact a human's sense of fast vs. slow, one would have to print some really huge values, or print a lot of big ints.  When I first answered I thought "what would anyone do with so much data" but if it is fed into another process, then yes it would matter.  Perhaps `print` is the output of a process which will be fed into another?

Comment: If you want to do it fast, write it to a file / fifo / socket, don't use `print`, is probably the answer.