# Arbitrary length integer to byte array conversion (Most significant byte first)

Tags: python-3.x

How can I convert an arbitrary length (positive) integer into a *bytes* object in Python 3? The most significant byte should be first so that it is basically a base 256 encoding.

For fixed length values (up to unsigned long long) you can use the [struct module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846045/371137) but there seems to be no library support for conversions of large numbers in Python.

**Expected results:**

```
>>> intToBytes(5)
b'\x05'
>>> intToBytes(256)
b'\x01\x00'
>>> intToBytes(6444498374093663777)
b'You won!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### No leading zero bytes in the result:

```
def intToBytes(num):
    if num == 0:
        return b""
    else:
        return intToBytes(num//256) + bytes([num%256])
```

or as a one-liner

```
intToBytes = lambda x: b"" if x==0 else intToBytes(x//256) + bytes([x%256])
```

Consecutively concatenating the constant *bytes* objects is not terribly efficient but makes the code shorter and more readable.

As an alternatve you can use

```
intToBytes = lambda x: binascii.unhexlify(hex(x)[2:])
```

which has `binascii` as dependency, though.

### Fixed length result (with leading zeros if necessary):

Starting with Python 3.2 you can use [int.to_bytes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) which also supports little-endian byte order.