# How to write int array [0,1,2,...] in binary to a file using Python script

Tags: python

I'm new to Python. I want to generate a 100K binary file. The file contents will be (in hex):

```
00000000 00000001 00000002 00000003
00000004 00000005 00000006 00000007
...
```

I read some examples, but they all write a string to a text file. That's not what I want.

Comment: Do you want literal zeros, commas, and x's in your file? If so, should there be spaces after the commas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you can use the `struct` module to pack each number into a four-byte binary string.  (See: [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846038/3308630))

Then, just loop from 0-25,000 and write each number to your file.  Since each number is four bytes, this will produce a 100K file.  For example:

```
import struct

f = open("filename","wb")
for i in range(25000):
    f.write(struct.pack('>I', i))
f.close()
```

Comment: if all of his values will fit in 8 bits, he could just use `chr`, correct?

Comment: @Broseph He could just use `chr` if he wanted 8-bit numbers, but he wanted 32-bit binary numbers in the file.

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. It is still possible to do this without struct, but that would be pointless. Unless this is homework and the teacher wants them to play with bits, lol.