# How do I convert an int representing a UTF-8 character into a Unicode code point?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, int

Let us use the character [Latin Capital Letter a with Ogonek (U+0104)](http://unicode-table.com/en/0104/) as an example.

I have an int that represents its UTF-8 encoded form:

```
my_int = 0xC484
# Decimal: `50308`
# Binary: `0b1100010010000100`
```

If use the `unichr` function i get: `\uC484` or `쒄` (U+C484)

But, I need it to output: `Ą`

How do I convert `my_int` to a Unicode code point?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm curious as to what kind of API yields UTF-8 
integers, though?

Comment: related: [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/846038/4279)

Answer (score 3):

To convert the integer `0xC484` to the bytestring `'\xc4\x84'` (the UTF-8 representation of the Unicode character `Ą`), you can use [`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack(">H", 0xC484)
'\xc4\x84'
```

... where `>` in the [format string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-strings) represents *big-endian*, and `H` represents *unsigned short int*.

Once you have your UTF-8 bytestring, you can decode it to Unicode as usual:

```
>>> struct.pack(">H", 0xC484).decode("utf8")
u'\u0104'

>>> print struct.pack(">H", 0xC484).decode("utf8")
Ą
```

Comment: utf-8 encoding can use different number of bytes to encode different Unicode codepoints (from a byte upto 4-bytes). `'>H'` works only for 2-bytes sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Encode the number to a hex string, using `hex()` or `%x`. Then you can interpret that as a series of hex bytes using the `hex` decoder. Finally use the `utf-8` decoder to get a unicode string:

```
def weird_utf8_integer_to_unicode(n):
    s= '%x' % n
    if len(s) % 2:
        s= '0'+s
    return s.decode('hex').decode('utf-8')
```

The `len` check is in case the first byte is in the range 0x1–0xF, which would leave it missing a leading zero. This should be able to cope with any length string and any character (however encoding a byte sequence in an integer like this would be unable to preseve leading zero bytes).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> int2bytes(0xC484).decode('utf-8')
u'\u0104'
>>> print(_)
Ą
```

where [`int2bytes()` is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524760/4279).