# Pack 4 chars into an int (Python)?

Tags: python

Is it possible to pack 4 chars into an int in python and have it be represented as one value in a bytearray? I'm looking into packing it into a struct, but run into an error if I try something like

`characters = b'abcd'
struct.pack('i',characters)`

Comment: In reverse: [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/846038/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain that I understand your problem -- If you want to take a bytestring and turn it into an integer, on python3.x, this is pretty easy:

```
import sys
value = int.from_bytes(b'abcd', sys.byteorder)  # for me, byteorder is `'little'`
assert value == 1684234849
```

On python2.x, you'd unpack the struct (which will work for python3.x too):

```
value, = struct.unpack('<i', b'abcd')
assert value == 1684234849
```

---

Now if you want to put this value into a bytearray -- The answer is no, you can't do that.  `bytearray` only accepts values `0` -> `255`