# Reversing the byte order of a string containing hexadecimal characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte

I have a long string with hexadecimal characters, for example:

```
string = "AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567"
```

I am using

```
string.to_bytes(4, 'little')
```

I would like the final string to be as follows:

```
6745230F33CC55AA0133CC55AA
```

but I am getting an error

> `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_bytes'`

What's wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes)

Answer (score 9):

[`to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) only works with integer, afaik.

You could use [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.fromhex):

```
>>> ba = bytearray.fromhex("AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567")
>>> ba.reverse()
```

To convert it back to string using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> s = ''.join(format(x, '02x') for x in ba)
>>> print(s.upper())
6745230F33CC55AA0133CC55AA
```

Comment: To convert it back to hex, you can simply call `s.hex()`

Answer (score 1):

To convert between little and big-endian you can use this `convert_hex` function based on `int.to_bytes` and `int.from_bytes`:

```
def int2bytes(i, enc):
    return i.to_bytes((i.bit_length() + 7) // 8, enc)

def convert_hex(str, enc1, enc2):
    return int2bytes(int.from_bytes(bytes.fromhex(str), enc1), enc2).hex()

be = "AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567"
convert_hex(be, 'big', 'little')
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice your question is very similar to [this question from 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes/58945031#58945031) . While the old thread asks for one-way conversion, and you ask for a "vice-versa" conversion, it is really the same thing, whichever endianness you start with. Let me show,

```
0x12345678 -> 0x78563412 -> 0x12345678
```

The conversion is very easy with `pwntools`, the tools created for software hacking. In particular, to avoid packing-unpacking mess, [pwntools embeds p32() function for exact this purpose](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/util/packing.html)

```
import pwntools

x2 = p32(x1)
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this the answer/code you are looking for?

```
def little(string):
 t= bytearray.fromhex(string)
 t.reverse()
 return ''.join(format(x,'02x') for x in t).upper()
little(s=AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567)
```

Comment: 33CC55AACC55AA016745230F this is what I would like  to have

Comment: for an input AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567 you would like output 33CC55AACC55AA016745230F?
is that what you want?

Comment: was your input 13495340714998364417400470979943, and thats why the input is AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567?

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you can reverse string one of  way would be

```
string = "AA55CC3301AA55CC330F234567"[::-1]
```

Comment: This is outright incorrect. To change endianness, reversing string seems right to us humans, but is incorrect nonetheless. For example, if we have the byte-array or "0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78", changed endianness output will be "0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12", but not "0x87 0x65 0x43 0x21

Comment: Well I can't +1 because this answer doesn't apply to Tim's question properly.  But I had a binary string that was little-endian, and a refresher of the [::-1] slicing trick was very helpful for that, so thank you.