# Why does Python return unexpected characters from the to_bytes() method?

Tags: python, type-conversion

Why do some of the integers passed to the `to_bytes()` method give a strange result?

```
>>> b = 5152
>>> b.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'\x14 '
>>> b = 5153
>>> b.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'\x14!'
>>> b = 16592
>>> b.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'@\xd0'
```

How to interpret `'@'`, `'!'`, `' '`? For 16592 I expected `b'\x40\xd0'`.

I read the Python 3 documentation and all examples from there work fine: [Python 3 to_byte() description](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=to_bytes#int.to_bytes).

```
>>> b = 1024
>>> b.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big')
b'\x04\x00'
```

I also try an example for [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes) and it works like a charm.

```
>>> b = 1245427
>>> b.to_bytes(3, byteorder='big')
b'\x13\x00\xf3'
```

I am using Python 3.6.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of a byte, interpreted as ASCII, is printable, then the `repr()` of that byte is the printable character.

Since the ASCII value of `@` is 0x40, these two values are equivalent `b'@'`, `b'\x40'`.

This may be more easily seen through demonstration than an explanation:

```
>>> b'\x40'
b'@'
```

But regardless of representation, that object is a `bytes` of length 1, with a value of 64 in the first byte:

```
>>> b'\x40'[0] == 64
True
>>> b'@'[0] == 64
True
```

Returning to your example, if you want to know the hex value of each byte, you can use `bytes.hex()`:

```
>>> b=16592
>>> b.to_bytes(2, byteorder='big').hex()
'40d0'
```