# How to convert and Integer to an 64-bit byte representation in python

Tags: python, byte

I am trying to convert an integer. E.g 3063294273, to a 64-bit big endian encoded byte representation.
So for example if I have a value = 1 my output should be
`0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01`

What would be the best approach to do this in python?

Edit: I saw the other question provided in [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes).
But in the other question, the author was not asking for a specific size of the output. Which is important for my problem.

Comment: Your example shows 128 bits (16 instances of 8-bit (two hex digit)) values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes)

Comment: I dont see the duplicate? In the provided other question, the author was not asking for a specific size of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)

```
>>> value = 1
>>> value.to_bytes(8, 'big')
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
```

(Your sample output is 128 bits, so if you meant that, use 16.)