# Convert hex string to usably hex

Tags: python, memory, hex

I want to convert a hex string I read from a file
"0xbffffe43" to a value written in little endian "\x43\xfe\xff\xbf".

I've tried using struct.pack but it requires a valid integer. Everytime I try to cast hex functions it will convert the 43. I need this for an assignment around memory exploits.

I have access to python 2.7

```
a = "0xbffffe43"
...
out = "\x43\xfe\xff\xbf"
```

Is what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *string* in input. You can convert it to an integer using `int` and a base.

```
>>> a = "0xbffffe43"
>>> import struct
>>> out = struct.pack("<I",int(a,16))
>>> out
b'C\xfe\xff\xbf'
```

The `b` prefix is there because solution was tested with python 3. But it works as python 2 as well.

`C` is printed like this because python interprets printable characters. But

```
>>> b'C\xfe\xff\xbf' == b'\x43\xfe\xff\xbf'
True
```

see:

- [Convert hex string to int in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209513/convert-hex-string-to-int-in-python)
- [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing:

```
my_hex = 0xbffffe43
my_little_endian = my_hex.to_bytes(4, 'little')
print(my_little_endian)
```

Comment: this doesn't work with python 2. Covered in the duplicate (for python 3)

Comment: Thanks, I did not know

Comment: besides OP has probably input defined as string.