# Extract public-key modulus from PrivateKey/CertificateRequest/Certificate in Python , with the same format as OpenSSL

Tags: python, openssl, pycrypto

using OpenSSL, i can extract the modulus of the public key from various objects with these commands:

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in {KEY}
openssl req -noout -modulus -in {CSR}
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in {CERT}
```

I am trying to replicate this within python, using `cryptography` or the `pyopenssl` package.

I can extract the public key from all of these objects in Python, but I can not figure out how to encode the modulus to match the OpenSSL commandline output -- which appears to be a base64 encoded version of a format that I can't figure out from the docs or source code of any of the 3 projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `RSAPublicNumbers` class ([link](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa.RSAPublicNumbers)) in cryptography has what you are looking for. You can get it using `to_cryptography_key` method ([link](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.PKey.to_cryptography_key)) of `PKey` class in pyopenssl.

```
from OpenSSL.crypto import load_certificate
from OpenSSL.crypto import FILETYPE_PEM

with open(certfile, 'rb') as fp:
    cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, fp.read())

# This gives you the modulus in integer form
modn = cert.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key().public_numbers().n

# Convert it to hex
print('{:X}'.format(modn))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had gotten as far as `cert.get_pubkey().to_cryptography_key().public_numbers()` myself...  but the hex formatting of `.n` was the missing piece that eluded me for oven an hour this morning!

Comment: to convert the number to bytes, see also [Convert a Python int into a big-endian string of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859903/10440128). ideally, the parser would expose the raw bytes, but well