# Creating byte array with integers larger than 256

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I am working on a Python application that sends a binary stream over serial to a microcontroller. My initial use case is simple - send 4 integers which represent the binary values to send over the serial port. I need to translate the array into a byte array or a stream of bits or bytes. Using `bytearray` works great unless one of my integers is > 256 (more than 1 byte).

Here is the code and the first 3 elements of the buffer list are 1 byte integers (<256). But the last element (`dataCRC`) is represented by a 14-bit integer (8444 in my case).

```
dataCRC = 8444
buffer = [128, 32, length]   
buffer.append(dataCRC)

barray = bytearray(buffer)
```

This raises the error that each byte must be in the range (0,256). How do I break up my last buffer element (the 14 bit number) into 2 bytes?

Comment: Which two bytes do you expect to be appended to the buffer for `dataCRC = 8444`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting int to bytes in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017698/converting-int-to-bytes-in-python-3), or better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846038/convert-a-python-int-into-a-big-endian-string-of-bytes